# Generate permalink to a blog post Hindi PHP

Tags: php, permalinks

I have one form in which following inputs are taken from user:

- Blog title
- Blog Description
- Permalink to access blog

I am converting Blog title to lower case and replacing white spaces with dash(-) and **storing it in `Permalink to access blog`** . 
Below is the code to handle this operation:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');

function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
  if( !empty($replace) ) {
     $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
  }
     $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
     $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
     $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
     $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
     return $clean;
}    

$prmlkn = toAscii($blog_headline, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-');
```

This code all works fine till `Blog headline` is in English. But if user types in `Hindi` then i am only getting `-` as permalink means it is not recognizing **Hindi POST values.**

Comment: It would be nice if you provided a sample input but the simple answer seems to be that hindi for example `नमस्ते` is not valid text for a url.

Comment: Say someone adds blog headline as `दर्शक इस लिंक पर वीडियो देख सकते हैं` then i want permalink to be as `दर्शक-इस-लिंक-पर-वीडियो-देख-सकते-हैं`

Comment: Based on (RFC 3986)[https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2] URLs may only contain characters in the ASCII-US subsection. however they can be encoded using percent encoding demonstrated in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Hindi uses the extended character set in UTF-8 and you are converting to ASCII that only provides latin characters, thus:

```
$str = "नमस्ते"
$clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str); // clean is an empty string ""
```

According to [rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2)

> 2. Characters
>
> ...
>
> The ABNF notation defines its terminal values to be non-negative
> integers (codepoints) based on the US-ASCII coded character set
> [ASCII].  Because a URI is a sequence of characters, we must invert
> that relation in order to understand the URI syntax.  Therefore, the
>
> integer values used by the ABNF must be mapped back to their
> corresponding characters via US-ASCII in order to complete the syntax
> rules.
>
> A URI is composed from a limited set of characters consisting of
> digits, letters, and a few graphic symbols.  A reserved subset of
> those characters may be used to delimit syntax components within a
> URI while the remaining characters, including both the unreserved set
> and those reserved characters not acting as delimiters, define each
> component's identifying data.

You might be better off using `urlencode()` but note this might make a really ugly and long permalink

```
$str = "नमस्ते hello";
$clean = urlencode("$str");
printf("%s",$clean);
```

would result in a valid but ulgy:

```
%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%87+hello
```